# C# Excel instance with visible as false and opening a file outside the application

Tags: c#, excel, interop

In my application, I create an excel file. To achieve this, I instanciate an Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application variable and  set its Visible member to False. When I have done this, I see my EXCEL.EXE process in the task manager.

The problem is I have to let this variable live throughout the application execution lifetime. So when I open an excel file outside of this application, it uses the Excel instance already existing and, because I set the Visible to false when creating it, I can't see my opened file.

Is there any way I can create my Excel instance in my application whilst saying "don't let this instance being used outside the application, if someone wants to open an Excel file outside of it, it can't use this instance, it must create a new Excel instance" ?

Thanks

```
internal Application _application;
_application = new Application()
{
    Visible = false,
    DisplayAlerts = false,
    ScreenUpdating = false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for can be achieved by specifying that Excel open each file in a new instance.

[This Microsoft Community page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/open-each-spreadsheet-in-a-new-instance-of-excel/8683864f-de1b-45ee-a519-c23a0e3a314b?auth=1) provides the below instructions:

> To resolve this, go to 'excel options' > click on the 'advanced' tab > scroll down to general > check the ignore other applications that use 'Dyanamic Data Exchange (DDE)'

The same page also provides an alternate solution that involves modifying the File Type options if this solution doesn't work.